# How should be a ggplot equivalent of plot + lines in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlay, density-plot

With `plot` and `lines` I can make multiple plots overlapped in the same range in R. For example, I can plot the density of a data and then simulate a density distribution in the same plot as follows:

```
plot(density(mtcars$mpg), col = "red")
polygon(density(mtcars$mpg), col = "red")
x <- seq(0, 50, length=1000)
hxn <- dnorm(x,mean=mean(mtcars$mpg), sd = sd(mtcars$mpg))
lines(x,hxn, col="green")
```

obtaining
[image]

How can I do the same (introduce both the density of the data `mtcars$mpg` and the simulation `(x,hxn)` in the same plot) with `ggplot`?
I would start by

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg))+geom_density(color = "red", fill = "red")+xlim(0,40)
```

but then I do not know how to overlay the `x,hxn` data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=mpg))+
  geom_density(color = "red", fill = "red")+ 
  xlim(0,40) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(mtcars$mpg), sd = sd(mtcars$mpg)))
```

[image]