# Plotting two stat_function()'s in a grid using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to output two plots in a grid using the same function but with different input for `x`. I am using `ggplot2` with `stat_function` as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091323/how-to-plot-a-function-curve-in-r) and I have combined the two plots as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23055467/12629562) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56563631/12629562).

```
f01 <- function(x) {1 - abs(x)}

ggplot() +
    stat_function(data = data.frame(x=c(-1, 1)), aes(x = x, color = "red"), fun = f01) +
    stat_function(data = data.frame(x=c(-2, 2)), aes(x = x, color = "black"), fun = f01)
```

With the following outputs:

Plot:

[image: my output]

Message:

```
`mapping` is not used by stat_function()`data` is not used by stat_function()`mapping` is not used by stat_function()`data` is not used by stat_function()
```

I don't understand why `stat_function()` won't use neither of the arguments. I would expect to plot two graphs one with `x` between `-1:1` and the second with x between `-2:2`. Furthermore it takes the colors as labels, which I also don't understand why. I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that according to the docs the data argument is

> Ignored by stat_function(), do not use.

Hence, at least in the second call to stat_function the data is ignored.

Second, the

> The function is called with a grid of evenly spaced values along the x axis, and the results are drawn (by default) with a line.

Therefore both functions are plotted over the same range of x values.

If you simply want to draw functions this can be achievd without data and mappings like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

f01 <- function(x) {1 - abs(x)}

ggplot() +
  stat_function(color = "black", fun = f01, xlim = c(-2, 2)) +
  stat_function(color = "red", fun = f01, xlim = c(-1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Where in the docs can I find the part that `data` is ignored? On the page for [`stat_function`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/stat_function.html) I couldn't find it

Comment: Type ?stat_function in the console. Then scroll down to the arguments.

Comment: ... or https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_function.html?q=stat%20_%20function#arguments

Comment: Thanks, apparently there was a change between 3.3.0 and 3.3.2 in the docs and you still find the old reference for `stat_function` (see my link above)

Comment: Yep. Just had a look in the change log. See https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/index.html. There have been some changes. In particular there is now a geom_function.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I'm not really sure what happens here with `ggplot` and its inner workings. It seems that the functions are always applied to the complete range, here -2 to 2. Also, there is an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3611) on github regarding a wrong error message for `stat_function`.

However, you can use the `xlim` argument for your `stat_function` to limit the range on which a function is drawn. Also, if you don't specify the `colour` argument by a variable, but by a manual label, you need to tell which colours should be used for which label with `scale_colour_manual` (easiest with a named vector). I also adjusted the line width to show the function better:

```
library(ggplot2)

f01 <- function(x) {1 - abs(x)}

cols <- c("red" = "red", "black" = "black")

ggplot() +
  stat_function(data = data.frame(x=c(-1, 1)), aes(x = x, colour = "red"), fun = f01, size = 1.5, xlim = c(-1, 1)) +
  stat_function(data = data.frame(x=c(-2, 2)), aes(x = x, colour = "black"), fun = f01) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = cols)
```

[image]